# Displaying Data from Text File on a Graph

Tags: java

Reading a .txt file using a file chooser and bufferedreader, I now need to display the data on a line graph. So the title from the text file will be at the top, with the axis labelled using the names given in the text file and the numbers plotted to make up the line graph. No idea where to begin with this as a complete beginner.

Comment: Apologies, changes have been made.

Comment: Added the code from the pastebin link to the post.

Comment: You opened the file .Ok. But where is the code for reading the file ? You need to open file for read only, store contents of the file to a string, close the file, set the string on the JTextArea

Comment: Why did you modify your post and remove EVERYTHING of value?

Comment: Please post a _new question_ if you have further problems. Answered question are preferred to be kept for archiving, so that other people can solve similar problems by reading your question.

Comment: Unable to post another question today

Answer (score 1):

Since you use local classes, you can *capture* the `text` variable (your `JTextArea`) and use it in the action listener code:

```
class openaction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Open a Text File");
        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        // ^^^ renamed this, so it doesn't hide 'text'      

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            // Read in lines.
            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                // Append each line, plus a newline, to the text area.
                br.lines().forEach(line -> text.append(line + System.lineSeparator()));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that operator is a Java beginner. He may not know how to work with this advanced technique. It would be good if you can also provide an explanation of how to embed the code in the given example.

Comment: @Zabuza He is already using it like this. He would just have to change the code in his ```openaction``` class.

Comment: Getting an error on this line:

     br.lines().forEach(line -> text.append(line + System.lineSeparator()));

Unsure how to amend this line to make it work?

Comment: @L.Wheeler Hmm, you might have an outdated version of the JDK. Are you not using Java 8? I can modify the code in that case.

Comment: I believe it is outdated yes.

Comment: Think the error is resolved, used a suggested fix in Eclipse. However there are still errors in the program, error displaying under the final } before the actionlistener for the Load button

Comment: Got it working. Could you just briefly explain how the text.append line works so I can comment my code in a bit more detail?

Comment: That is some newer syntax in Java. `br.lines()` returns an iterable object containing lines, as `String`. You then simply use `text.append(...)` which appends a given String to the text area. Maybe the following equivalent code (for this line) is easier to understand as it uses the common Java syntax: http://pastebin.com/szmrhn6q

Comment: @L.Wheeler Yes :). This using a [_lambda expression_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Basically, if you have an ```interface``` with only 1 method, you can use a lambda expression to create an instance of that interface (in the case of ```forEach```, the interface is [```Consumer<...>```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)). We are writing the code for the 1 method on the interface, with it's 1 argument, that I've called ```line``` here.

Comment: As a novice that went right over my head. Is there any way to explain that in more simple terms?

Comment: @L.Wheeler Let's see. In some cases, you want to pass just a method instead of a whole object, as an argument. In that case, you can usually pass a lambda expression. But instead of the traditional ```public void method(String arg1) {<code>}```, the syntax is ```(<arguments>) -> {<code>}```. Or in the special case of 1 argument, and only 1 line of code: ```<arguement> -> <1 line of code>```. Most of the types (like ```String```, ```int``` etc.) can be deduces (or _inferred_) automatically, so they don't need to be typed out, which usually makes for shorter code.